# Get the predicted value with Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, statistics

Say I have a have a plot with the following information:

[image: scatterplot]

Based on this R code:

```
concentration <- c(1,10,20,30,40,50)
signal <- c(4, 22, 44, 244, 643, 1102)
plot(concentration, signal)
res <- lm(signal ~ concentration)
abline(res)
```

How do I get the value of signal for concentration 45 in R, for example? I mean, how can I obtain the value that `abline` used to plot the line in this particular point?

I suppose I could get the β1 and β2 and do the math by myself, but I'm interested in understanding how this could be done automatically in R.

Comment: Try this: `predict(res, newdata=data.frame(concentration=45))`. Also `?predict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `predict`. The trick is that you have to put your predictors into a new data.frame with appropriate names so it knows what to predict on:

```
predict(res,data.frame(concentration=45))
       1 
779.5875
```

Comment: I had already tried `predict` but your answer helped me realize my mistake. Thanks!